# ValueError: Data must not be a string / HTTP 415

Tags: file-upload, https, python-requests

I'm trying to upload image using it's private API. It keeps throwing me ValueError. I'm not entirely sure weather I need to pass in the unique signature key or not(The actual post request that I got doesn't pass the signature key however I'm using requests session that should indicate I'm an authenticated member) 
[The POST request I got from the sniffer(mitmproxy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aREME.png)
As shown in the picture it doesn't pass in any signature_body whatsoever. So I'm assuming I don't need to pass the signature key? Anyways. When I put the signature key and the files parameter it throws me Data must not be string error.

```
def upload_images(self):
        data = {'_csrftoken':self.LastResponse.cookies['csrftoken'],
                'guid':self.uuid,
                'device_id':self.device_id
                }
        files = {
        'photo':open('small.jpg','rb')
        }
        make_post_requests = self.s.post('https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/upload/photo/', self.generateSignature(json.dumps(data)), files=files)
        print make_post_requests.text
```

That code throws me the ValueError. And if I get rid of self.generateSignature(json.dumps(data)) and just put files=files.
It throws me the HTTP 415 error. Here's the code.

```
def upload_images(self):
        data = {'_csrftoken':self.LastResponse.cookies['csrftoken'],
                'guid':self.uuid,
                'device_id':self.device_id
                }
        files = {
        'photo':open('small.jpg','rb')
        }
        make_post_requests = self.s.post('https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/upload/photo/', files=files, data=data)
        print make_post_requests.text

<html>
<head><title>415 Unsupported Media Type</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>415 Unsupported Media Type</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions -
1. Do I need to pass the unique signature key? As the post requests clearly show it doesn't need to be passed except csrftoken and other attributes.
2. If I don't need to pass the signature key, what am I doing wrong that it throws me HTTP 415 error. I'm following the instagram upload picture rules.
3. If I do need to pass the signature key, how do I pass the signature key and files both together at one requests? 
4. Does this maybe has to do with passing content-header? If so how do I generate one? According to the requests it passes multipart with like a unique boundary number.